# Statsmodels ARIMA: Constant Value for Each Forecast

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to use statsmodels' ARIMA to forecast a time series.  I'm using sklearn's `TimeSeriesSplit` to evaluate my models.  Unfortunately, when I forecast the next fold of data (which has true value `Y_test`), I get a constant prediction:

```
if is_arima:
      Y_train = Y_train.astype(float)
      # build basic ARIMA model
      arima_model = ARIMA(Y_train, order=(2,0,1))
      # fit it, using exogenous variables
      arima_results = arima_model.fit()
      # predict next len(test) values, using exogenous variables (X_test)
      preds = arima_results.forecast(steps=len(Y_test))[0]
      print(preds)
```

Which gives me:

```
115.65096239  120.89113477  121.52020239  121.59572014  121.60478583
  121.60587414  121.60600479  121.60602047  121.60602235  121.60602258
  121.6060226   121.60602261  121.60602261  121.60602261  121.60602261
  121.60602261  121.60602261  121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226
  121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226
  121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226   121.6060226...
```

This makes me think my ARIMA isn't using the prediction at time t for its prediction at time t+1?

I understand the output isn't perfectly constant but my dataset shows large variation, so this is mildly concerning.  Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the estimated parameters? My guess is that there is very little persistence, and the forecast revert to the mean relatively fast. If large variation in the data is not strongly autocorrelated, then long term prediction with ARMA will not catch the fluctuation.

Comment: The flat forecast tels you  about your data as Rob Hydman points out as "there is no trend, no seasonality, and insufficient temporal dynamics to allow the future observations to have different conditional means."

Comment: Did you get the solution on this?How did you solve this problem,?@bclyaman

Answer (score 0):

Your using `ARIMA` with `order=(2,0,1)`, so your prediction is

> x(t) = constant + w(t) + a1 * x(t-1) + a2 * x(t-2) + b1 * w(t-1)

So, your prediction depends on 2 factors.  You have

- **A**uto**R**egressive terms: are just a constant times the prior period's value plus a different constant times the value 2 periods ago.

> a1 * x(t-1) + a2 * x(t-2)

- **M**oving **A**verage term, which is a constant time error from the prior period's prediction.

> b1 * w(t-1)

So your model is probably mostly dominated by the prior 2 periods, and it probably finds an equilibrium rather quickly.

Try printing out the parameters and then plugging them into Excel to see what is happening in the model.

```
print(arima_model.summary())
print(arima_model.params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of recursive strategy to do multi step prediction i.e. forecasts generated in the prior steps are used for the prediction of next forecasts iteratively. It leads to error accumulation and as a result forecasting converges to a value.
Arima does not perform well for very long data series.